# Spring boot + Hibernate + SqlAzure pagination issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, azure, pagination

I have a java spring boot application that use hibernate as ORM. The database is an Azure SQL Server.

I've enabled the setShowSql  on vendor adapter configuration.

When I want to find objects, I used the TypedQuery's methods `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` and than invoke the `getResultList` method.

The query printed in the console doesn't contains the OFFSET and ROW FETCH clauses and it seems that Hibernate first retrieve all result and than apply the pagination on the resulted list.

This obviously causes performance issues.

Where am I doing wrong?

Below I report the sample code I used.

```
query.setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset());
query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
...
query.getResultList()
```

Comment: Which Dialect are you using?  Also does your query contain an `ORDER BY` fragment or is the results unordered?

Comment: I've tried with all dialect. The actual dialect I'm using is org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect. Regarding the ordeer by fragment, yes, I've included and see it on printed query. Today I've tried the latest stable versione of hibernate but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time Hibernate will explicitly include the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses under a SQL Server dialect will be when the following conditions are met:

1. You must use `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect` or any future 2012+ version.
2. Your query must include an `ORDER BY` clause.
3. Your query is not executing a `TOP` clause query.

The `SQLServer2012Dialect` uses a customized `LimitHandler` implementation called `SQLServer2012LimitHandler` that you can see [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/pagination/SQLServer2012LimitHandler.java#L38) that explicitly handles this use case or otherwise falls back to the old behavior.

If both of the requirements above are being met but the logic is still fallig back to the old behavior for some reason, then it's a bug.  In that case, you probably should update [HHH-12152](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12152) with a test case so we can fix it.

Comment: Thank you!! My problem was in the Spring configuration. When I set the property hibernate.version to 5.2.12.Final it works well!